# How to move marker and the camera synchronously and always place marker to centre of camera position IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want the GMSMarker to move to camera. this is my code

```
 -(void)addMap {

        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                                longitude:longitude
                                                                     zoom:15];
        GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, [Util window_width],[Util window_height]);
        mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:newFrame camera:camera];
        mapView.delegate = self;
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = camera.target;
        marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
        marker.icon =[Util imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"set_address.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(170, 65)];
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.map = mapView;
        [self.MapContentView addSubview:mapView];


     }
```

I have a marker on the map, normally it is located at the center of the map if user does not scroll the map.

When the user scroll the map, I want  marker to move to the new location, along with the camera  , so it is always centered of the map  .

**I try the following code for it**

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    [mapView animateToLocation:marker.position];


    return YES;
}


- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{

    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

    NSLog(@"camera.target.latitude %f,%f",camera.target.latitude,camera.target.longitude);

    latitude=camera.target.latitude;
    longitude=camera.target.longitude;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture
{
    [self recenterMarkerInMapView:mapView];
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    [self recenterMarkerInMapView:mapView];
}

- (void)recenterMarkerInMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
{
    // Get the center of the mapView
    CGPoint center = [mapView convertPoint:mapView.center fromView:self.view];

    // Reset the marker position so it moves without animation
    [mapView clear];
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone;
    marker.position = [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:center];
    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

Comment: When i did that marker blinks alot while moving cant we make it smooth

Comment: Does it **jump** (from the dragged direction to the center) or does it **hide and show**. Also, are you holding a reference to the marker?

Comment: when i use kGMSMarkerAnimationPop it hide and show. If i use kGMSMarkerAnimationNone it jumps. Is there any way to place in center only

Comment: You can try using the mapView:willMove method as well (see the edited answer), but since they get called after the user interaction there will always be a delay... a hack would be to place a UIImageView (w/ the marker image) on top of your map and show it while the user is moving (and hide the GMSMarker) and hide it when the animation is finished (and show the GMSMarker)...

Comment: it still does blink cant we make it fixed in centre of screen

Comment: Looks like if you want a perfectly stable solution you'd have to use a separate UIImageView and manually trigger the visibility of an marker image vs actual GMSMarker...

Comment: tqs i have used the button any way

Comment: any ideas to change the coordinate of     mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

Comment: I haven't found a way to achieve the perfectly centered marker... maybe we have to come up with a hack...

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4. To move the selected marker to centre of mapView.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {  
      mapView.animate(toLocation: marker.position)   
      return true 
 }
```